# Union Alternative of HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to rewrite this query to improve performance given that it takes more than 10 mins to execute. I believe the issue is mainly due to the large Inbox table. As union isn't an option in HQL, what can I do to improve this performance? Thanks in advance.

```
select distinct p from PrReq p, Inbox i  where  i.documentNo in 
(select distinct kdn.kdnId from PrKdn kdn where kdn.prReqId = p ) or  
i.documentNo in (select distinct grn.grnId from PrGrn grn where
grn.prReqId = p) and i.inboxStatus = 0 and i.moduleStatus =
:currentStatus and p.recvDept.code = :dept  and p.organization = :org
order by p.billToDept, p.prId ASC, p.createDate desc
```

Comment: Try adding index to required your columns at db side and then check your performance.

Comment: You can use union as of Hibernate 6, but I guess that you are just missing an index.